# Populating a DataGrid using a Parameterised SQL Server Stored Procedure

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

I'm a newb to Visual Studio and VB and need a little help.

I've created a project in Visual Studio 2012 Express with:

1. a **Data Connection** to a SQL Server DB
2. within that a **Data Set**
3. a **Data Source/TableAdaptor** which is linked to
4. a **Stored Procedure**.

It seems difficult to see what Data Connections, Data Sets, Data Sources and Table Adaptors have been created and I'm slightly confused why 1 and 2 aren't the same thing.

The Stored Procedure accepts parameters and provides results based on those parameters.

In preview - it all works fine.

Now, I'm trying to populate a Data Grid with the data from the Data Source using supplied parameters when a button is pressed.  This is where I'm falling down. I've instantiated the TableAdaptor

```
Private Sub btnReport_Click_1(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs) Handles btnReport.Click
    Dim tableAdapter As New JBDataSet.p_Utility_UnLocked_TasksDataTable()

    Me.MyDataGrid.DataSource = tableAdapter.GetData("Report", "1234")

End Sub
```

I think the first line (Dim) correctly instantiates the tableAdapter but I know the second line is incorrect. I've looked all over and cannot find out what I need to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What's the compile-time type of `tableAdapter`? Just hover over it in VS and check.

My guess is that it's a `DataTable`:

```
Dim tableAdapter As New JBDataSet.p_Utility_UnLocked_TasksDataTable()
```

Because the object you are referencing is called Tasks **DataTable**.

You usually use DataAdapter [like this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bh8kx08z.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1):

```
Dim queryString As String = _
  "SELECT CustomerID, CompanyName FROM dbo.Customers"
Dim adapter As SqlDataAdapter = New SqlDataAdapter(queryString, connection)

Dim customers As DataSet = New DataSet
adapter.Fill(customers, "Customers")
```